# Displaying Tooltip on right end of control with arrow background color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip

How do I display tool tip to right end of control with arrow facing to right end of control and change background color of arrow to red?

[This is what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/t5tLG/)

```
<input id="age" title="test tooltip">
 $( document ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "right bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
    });
 .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: black;
     }
  .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;    
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;

  }
  .arrow {
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
  }
  .arrow.top {
    top: -16px;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .arrow.left {
    left: 20%;
  }
  .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    tranform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .arrow.top:after {
    bottom: -20px;
    top: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried in tooltip options 'placement':'right' ?

Comment: no, I am using  my: "left center",
        at: "right+10 center", to position it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

So, you want this :

[image: Demo2]

First, get rid of your `.arrow` class, and add this in your CSS :

```
.ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: calc(50% - 10px); /* Calculates the half height minus 10px */
    left: -10px;
    border-color: transparent red;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
```

Then, to position your tooltip to the right, use this in your JS:

```
position: {          
   my: 'right center', 
   at: 'left-10 center'
   ...
}
```

[Here's a demo to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/t5tLG/2/).

About `calc()` : *Method of allowing calculated values for length units, i.e. width: calc(100% - 3em)*

[It's supported in major desktop browser.](http://caniuse.com/calc)

---

### Old answer (will be deleted after acceptance)

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

[image: Demo]

Change your Javascript position for:

```
position: {
    my: "left bottom-20",
    at: "center top",
    ...
```

And for the red arrow, add this in your CSS:

```
.arrow:after{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was wrongly pointed. I am trying arrow to be pointing to right wall of textbox not below the textbox. here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t5tLG/1/

Comment: @Usham Your question was not really clear. I'll update shortly!

Answer (score 1):

```
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  height: 45px;
  left: 62px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 81px;
}
.arrow.top {
  bottom: -1px;
}
.arrow.left {
  left: -21%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky since Jquery UI does a lot in the background to try positioning the tooltip.

**Check out my fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pa5N8/1/

I've modified `.arrow.left` class to display a left-facing arrow using css borders, and positioned it appropriately to the center of the input field wall.

This is ideal if your input fields have consistent width and heights.  Otherwise, I'd recommend using a different library like tipsy: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Good luck!